# Cockcroft-Walton Multiplier strange voltage values

Tags: high-voltage, multiplier

I am building a circuit that allows me to generate high DC voltages that can be used in conjunction with a 3He counter tube to detect slow neutron radiation. The circuit was designed by someone else but I have transformed the schematic into a PCB and have been testing it. My problem is that the voltage on its output is much smaller than what I am expecting. I am able to read up to 800VDC on the final stages of the CW-multiplier (my current build is seeing more like 120VDC so this is for previous builds) but the output only measures around 60-90VDC. I have a few theories, but I am still not certain as to the cause. The design is based off the one outlined in this paper by Bob Higgins (http://physicsopenlab.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/SlowNeutronCoronaCounterTubes_1v10-1.pdf).

The basic explanation to the circuit is 5VDC is fed into the MAX1605 switching regulator and also a nearby transformer (1:20) which steps the voltage up to about 100V (~175KHz). The transformer's primary is grounded through the switching regulator and by controlling the current flow through the primary, (switching on and off quickly) it creates the changing magnetic field needed by the transformer. This 100VAC signal is fed into the 5 stage CW multiplier were it is boosted to around 1.8KV. This is connected to a 4.7M resistor whose other side is connected to the feedback line to the MAX1605 (100M and 50M in series) and the HV output (100M resistor trace). The feedback line is supposed to drop the output to 1.25V which is the switching threshold for the regulator. When the HV output is connected to the 3He tube and a neutron interaction occurs, the tube should draw current and R6 drops that 1.8kV down to ~750V to regulate the current flow. This small current is detected by another circuit and then produces a smoother signal (but this is unrelated). A more detailed explanation can be found in the paper linked above.

**Theory 1:** The feedback line to the fast switching regulator (MAX1605) may be creating a voltage divider that drops the voltage at the intended HV output. This seems to be the most likely case, however when I measure the voltage drop from the output of the multiplier (left side of R4) to the HV output I only measure .6V so I am a bit confused as to where this drop occurs.

**Theory 2:** I have gone through several iterations of the board as I thought maybe there were issues with the regulator (burnt out from hot air soldering), this is why my output voltage readings vary so much (60-90VDC). When I measure the feedback voltage at the regulator I see 133mV DC. This makes me think that the regulator is not working correctly but I am still able to measure higher voltages at the multiplier output (R4). My current build is only outputting around 130VDC measured at R4 (but previous ones have gotten as high as 8-900VDC as mentioned) so there definitely seems to be an issue with the regulator in this build, but the transformer still seems to be doing its job so it must be switching. Maybe the there is an issue in the CW multiplier like a blown cap or diode?

Any ideas are appreciated, I know this is a wall of text but I wanted to be thorough. If you have any questions dont hesitate to ask.
[image: Circuit schematic from EAGLE]
[image: Board Design from EAGLE]

Comment: How are you measuring voltages around the 100M resistors? With a 10M impedance DMM?

Comment: Please refer to the MAX1605EVKIT for a proper layout: https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1605EVKIT.pdf -- one thing that stands out is your FB net (which is a sensitive high-impedance input) is much too long. Would be better to place resistors R2, R3, R5 as close as possible to the MAX1605, minimizing the area of the FB net. (*Note: I am a Maxim Integrated applications engineer ~30 years, we make these evaluation kits to help you succeed, so please copy the design as closely as you can.*)

Comment: You may also find this Maxim tutorial useful: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/1/1109.html -- "TUTORIALS 1109 SMALL, HIGH-VOLTAGE BOOST CONVERTERS" -- goes into some detail about design considerations, and shows what kind of switching waveforms you should expect to measure with your oscilloscope. You won't be able to see what you need to see with only a DMM.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Yes, I was measuring the voltages using a DMM (Innova 3340a). This DDM claims a 10M input impedance but does not specify that is the impedance used specifically by the voltage testing circuitry (although I assume it is). I also measured the output waveforms using a digital oscilloscope and got the same 60-90VDC output measured on the HV output pad.

Comment: @MarkU Thank you for the information, I am still an EE student so while not familiar with evaluations kits, it looks like it could be a huge help to me. Concerning your tip about placing the FB net closer to the regulator I assume you are talking about the whole trace (NET) and not just the literal resistors. I placed grounding planes on the top and bottom of board in hopes that this would lessen the chances of that happening, do grounding planes not offer much protection in this regard?

Comment: Another question I have is related to grounding of this circuit. When testing the board with my oscilloscope I connected the ground pad with the ground clip on the probe (Earth ground) and there was a large spark. So while the circuit nominally produces a 1.8KV potential between its ground and output, this is still well above the earth reference used by the DSO. Would it provide any advantage (besides safety) to the circuit if i used earth as the ground potential?